# can you declare an empty array, without knowing the type in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, creation

for example:

```
let myArray:[] = []
```

or

```
let myArray = []
```

Comment: you don't need semi-colons anymore

Answer (score 3):

The first one is not possible (it will complain about expected element type) If you don't know the element type you can use AnyObject but if you know the type of it you have to put it there (Int,Double,String, AnyObject, etc...).

```
var myArrayOfDoubles:[Double] = []
```

The second one (when omitting the type) is OK ONLY if you initialize it with some values but If you try it with an empty array you won't be able to append anything (at least using Playground) saying that NSArray does not have a member named append.

```
var myArrayOfInts = [1,2,3,4,5]          //   [Int]
var myArrayOfAnyObject:[AnyObject] = []  //   [AnyObject]
```

And finally last but not least you have to define it as var because if you define it using let it will stay empty forever :)

Comment: At least this is a good habit you should always use let and if Xcode complains you just change it to var :)

Answer (score 0):

No. If you don't know what will go in use this:

```
var myArray = [Any]()
```

Apple has introduced a Type-GeStaPo and you must type anything that's not up the tree at count three.

To add to this use

```
myArray.append("this")
myArray.append(1)
myArray.append(myObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, it can be Any or Anyobject...
example:

```
var noTypeArray = [Any]()
```

If you want to fill the array eventually it may be var, no let, there's no point otherwise.